# Why don't these properties in the media query work?

Tags: css

when resizing the window to below 423 pixels, the width of `.form_2` isn't adjusted to 120%, same as for `.allIsWel`.

```css
@media (max-width: 423px) {

    .form_2 {
              width: 120%;
            }

    .allIsWel {
                width: 53%;
                margin-left: 23.5;
              }
}

    .form_2 {
             background-color: white;
             height: 400px;
             width: 400px;
             margin-top: -120px;
             border: 3px solid #e95f1d;
             border-radius: 3%;
             box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px #e95f1d;
             padding-top: 30px;
             }

     .allIsWell {
                 width: 160px;
                 height: 11%;
                 margin-top: 10%;
                 margin-left: 120px;
                 font-size: 35px;
                 font-family: 'Spicy Rice', cursive;
                 background-color: #e95f1d;
                 border-radius: 7px;
                 }
```

Comment: Maybe add your html and rest of the code ?

Comment: The whole html and css code, or just certain blocks you need ??

Comment: Just the code needed to reproduce your problem, you can check how to produce a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You must provide something as close as your code.

Comment: I posted everything ..

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593143/9636400

Comment: Thank you sir .. 
so, I should always put all media queries at the end of the code ..,??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media (max-width: 423px) {

.form_2 {
         transform: scale(1.2); /* Standard syntax */
         -ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari */
        }

.allIsWel {
            width: 53%;
            margin-left: 23.5;
          }
```

Comment: Put one of them from .form_2. This are just different browsers

Comment: I tried it .. but not working so.